# MobilePush SDK - Contact Key with using Data Cloud(CDP)

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, salesforce-cdp, datacloud

I'm struggling with understanding how MobilePush SDK's Contact Key works.

I refered to some former question like [Mobile Push SDK Contact Key](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/257464/mobile-push-sdk-contact-key), [Mobile Push SDK Functionality](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/250275/mobile-push-sdk-functionality).
Since these questions are about MC Connect issue, I was wondering what should I do when it comes to Data Cloud(CDP) not Sales Cloud.

I have to set Contact Key for MobilePush. As I understanding it should be cutomer data in app. (ex. customer ID, emailAddress etc)

If I using Data cloud, I have to use Subscriber Key(Contact Key) to 'Individual ID' which is in Data Cloud. And it is not in our mobile app.

In this case, how can I match data cloud contacts and mobilepush contacts?

(+ I found the document [Connect Mobile Apps to Data Cloud](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.c360_a_set_up_mobile_web_connection.htm&type=5). Is this could be solution?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Contact Key` (aka Subscriber Key) is the identifying piece of data used in Marketing Cloud to enable cross-channel interactions.

If you call `setProfileId`, the SDK gives that value to both CDP and Marketing Cloud. Those modules communicate with the appropriate servers to populate the data used for their features.