# mobile push SDK - contact key setting with cdp

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, sdk, salesforce-cdp

Follow-up Question for: [MobilePush SDK - Contact Key with using Data Cloud(CDP)](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/401307/mobilepush-sdk-contact-key-with-using-data-cloudcdp)

1. I'm going to set Contact key on mobilepush SDK in Marketing Cloud.
   If I'm using MC and CDP together, do I need to connect to both Marketing cloud and CDP?
   So that SDK gives value to both CDP and Marketing Cloud?
2. Is it okay if I set the `setProfileId` with email address? (that is the only identifier in mobile app)
3. If so, is it mapping contacts and app data with email address,and still subscriber key is individual id?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setProfileId` is the correct method to assign an identifier to both Marketing Cloud and CDP. There is a contact resolution that can happen under the hood without those keys aligned, but it certainly makes things easier if you just set the identifier :)

You can use whatever unique identifier for the contact that you wish.

I have no idea what you're asking in #3, but I would say it definitely depends on your use-case.

Comment: Appreciate for your help, Bill!